# Installing python site-packages in virtual environment

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtual-environment

Well, I have already installed python and some site-packages (including pandas) but I have learned about virtual enviroments and want to use it. I want to install pandas to my VE. 
First of all, I did this:

```
(python_venv) denis@denis-laptop:~$ pip3 install pandas
```

And got:

```
...
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Отказано в доступе: '/environments/python_venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/six.py'
```

So, I did:

```
(python_venv) denis@denis-laptop:~$ pip3 install --user pandas
```

Got:

```
...
Installing collected packages: numpy, six, python-dateutil, pytz, pandas
Successfully installed numpy-1.15.4 pandas-0.23.4 python-dateutil-2.7.5 pytz-2018.7 six-1.11.0
```

But I haven't got pandas in pip3 list:

```
(python_venv) denis@denis-laptop:~$ pip3 list --format=columns
Package       Version
------------- -------
pip           9.0.1  
pkg-resources 0.0.0  
setuptools    39.0.1
```

What should I do? I have Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a permission issue: you should be able to write files in your virtual environment as your user and the `--user` option should omitted. I suggest you change the ownership of the virtualenv as follows:

`chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) /environments/python_venv`

and then try the first `pip install pandas` again

Comment: Oh, great! It really works! Thank you but why it happened? Was it my fault?

Comment: check the ownership of the folder `ls -la /environment`, you might have created the virtualenv with `sudo`, you should however run it as user instead.
I suggest you change the whole `/environments` ownership to your user, so, next time when you create the virtualenv you won't have any more issues

Answer (score 0):

Considering `Successfully installed numpy-1.15.4 pandas-0.23.4` you probably have it installed. Did you try running `pip list --user`?

You have installed pandas to user install folder and possibly this does not show in the general `pip list` command. You can notice that the output of `pip list` is missing not only `pandas` but actually all the packages you installed with `pip3 install --user pandas`. Btw., there is no need to specify `--format=columns`, as it's the default.